# Scripting login to mysql with a string with special characters

Tags: scripting, mysql, escape-characters

I have a script which i want to auto-login inside a mysql database.

The problem is when the password has special characters, here an example:

Password file contains:

`password=$AES-256$VlQ==$+rZfd6ntjZdyD0=`

And this is the script:

```
pass=$(cat password_file | grep password | cut -d"=" -f2)
mysql -uroot -p$pass
```

How could this be done? Maybe trying to escape

I know even the cut part is just cutting the password in half.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po "(?<=^password=).*" file
```

With `sed`

```
grep "^password" file | sed 's/[^=]*=//'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'password=' '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't grep, just source the file:

```
. /path/to/password.txt
```

You now have your password saved as `$password`, so you can do:

```
mysql -uroot -p"$password"
```